# Construct a manufactured solution of Poisson's equation with Chebyshev/Fourier expansions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, poissons-equation, chebyshev-polynomials

I am solving a nonlinear Poisson's equation numerically using a mixed Chebyshev/Fourier spectral methods. Thus, assuming $x$ is periodic and $y$ is nonperiodic. I am trying to test my current numerical method/solver by using the method of manufacturing solution (MMS). Additionally, I am applying some coordinate mapping or rescaling my Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices to an arbitrary domain [a,b] by performing a change of variables as the following:
$$
y_L = (1/2)\left[ (b-a)y+(b+a) \right]
$$
Thus, my chebyshev derivatives can be rewritten as:
$$
D_L = D \left[ \frac{2}{b-a} \right]
$$
The two above expressions were taken from the Weideman and Reddy paper found in this post:
[Are there any alterations for the Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices on an arbitrary domain [a,b]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860823/are-there-any-alterations-for-the-chebyshev-differentiation-matrices-on-an-arbit/2276964#2276964)

**I)** As an initial step I solved the **linear** Poisson's equation with the rescaled Chebyshev derivatives:
$$
\nabla^2 u = S
$$
where BCs are periodic in x and zero Dirichlet in y as $u(x,a)=0$ & $u(x,b)=0$.

For the simple above case the test I performed with the MMS is:
$$
u(x,y)=(y-a)(y-b)\sin{Ax}
$$
The above case works perfectly for me and I have no issue at all.

**II)** However, when I try to do the same for the **nonlinear** Poisson's equation with following expression:
$$
\nabla \cdot (n\nabla u) = S
$$
or can be expanded as: $n \nabla^2 u + \nabla u \cdot \nabla n = S$

Then, using the MMS I chose $u(x,y)$ and $n(x,y)$ similarly as the first case:
$$
u(x,y)=(y-a)(y-b)\sin{Ax}
$$
$$
n(x,y)=y^2\sin{3Ax}+10
$$
The above expressions were chosen sort of in an arbitrary way so that they satisfy my BCs. However, the above case with the nonlinearity added (i.e. $n(x,y)$) does not work for me and I am trying to figure out if my choice of $n(x,y)$ is incorrect or if something else is going on in my numerical solver that I can fix. Is there a more robust way to test the second case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the correct form of $n(x,y)$ that satisfies the BCs in my main post:

\begin{equation}
n(x,y)=\left(\frac{2}{b-a}\right)\left[y-\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \right]^2\sin{3Ax}+10
\end{equation}